# C#, invalid token '='

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace HowTo
{
    class Variables
    {
        private List<recMessage> = new List<recMessage>();
    }
}



Error   1   Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration G:\GPRS\How-To Using the Comm Port_CS\How-To Using the Comm Port_CS\Variables.cs    9   34  How-To Using the Comm Port_CS
```

Where is this error coming from? I've done this a dozen times without this problem.

Comment: What's the name of the variable you're trying to declare?

Comment: you need a name: private List<recMessage> name = new List<recMessage>();

Comment: you need to name your variable, like `private List<recMessage> messages = new List<recMessage>();`

Comment: You forgot to name your list

Comment: I wonder how you've done this a dozen times without this problem, though haha

Comment: This human mistake happens to everybody, even the more experienced programmers. The reason you're getting downvotes, however, is because the VS error is pretty obvious and you'd have seen it yourself, if you had only spent 3 minutes staring at the erroneous code. Research effort is not limited to using Google, you know?

Comment: I agree and my apologies to everyone. Feel free to call me a damn noob, lack of sleep, too much caffeine and a deadline to hand my project in... I am quite embarassed to be honest...

Answer (score 11):

Add name of variable:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace HowTo
{
    class Variables
    {
        private List<recMessage> nameofvariable = new List<recMessage>();
    }
}
```

Comment: You couldn't be more correct, but I wonder why all the answers are getting so many upvotes :P

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the name of your List:

```
private List<recMessage> myList = new List<recMessage>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the name of the variable List:

```
private List<recMessage> list = new List<recMessage>();
```